# MS Excel - How to Get Min/Max columns values?

Tags: excel

Total sheet

```
Test Number | Value | Total Time
Test1       | Hello | =(Test1!B6 - Test1!B2)
Test2       | Hello | =(Test2!B2000 - Test2!B3)
Test3       | Hello | =(Test3!B3000 - Test3!B4)
```

Test1 sheet

```
Hello | 2134567
World | 2135567
Lorem | 2136567
Ipsum | 2137567
Hello | 2138567
```

I need Excel to dynamically find the first and last "Hello" in `Test1` and subtract the B column values. The first one should be 2138567 - 2134567.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not very elegant but working on my test:

`{=INDEX(INDIRECT(A4&"!B:B"),MAX(IF(INDIRECT(A4&"!A:A")=B4,ROW(INDIRECT(A4&"!A:A")),0)))-INDEX(INDIRECT(A4&"!B:B"),MATCH(B4,INDIRECT(A4&"!A:A"),0))}`

[image]

Validate with `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`ENTER`